# Team Foundation Server 2015 vs. Bitbucket Server (Stash)

Tags: tfs, bitbucket, bitbucket-server, tfs-2015

I am trying to compare two solutions. TFS Server 2015 and Bitbucket Server. I assume, that I will host GIT repositories and for project management I have other tools.

What is the advantage in using TFS comparing to Atlassian solutions?

Is there a place where I can find list of functionalties, implemented or scheduled in both tools development?

And is this post actual:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/08/27/git-experience-futures.aspx?CommentPosted=true&PageIndex=3#comments ?

Comment: This post will most likely be qualified as primarily opinion-based. However, I'd like to leave this comment: if you only consider TFS as a Git-hosting platform, it isn't worth it. The strong side of TFS is the integration of various aspects of ALM. Using just one little thing doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I generally agree. But I am looking for arguments, not for opinions.

Answer (score 0):

Bitbucket Server Features, you can refer to: https://www.atlassian.com/software/bitbucket/features

TFS with Git, you can refer to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Code/git/overview

In addition, you can try Visual Studio Online, just create an account then you can start share your code in git: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/code/share-your-code-in-git-vs

Comment: Tanks. I have both solutions installed and testing/comparing features. But it is time consuming and really I don't know if I see all features. Features listed on Atlassian site are only few subjects that can be analysed.
Whereas your TFS with GIT is not about server. Git usage isn't a problem here.

Comment: I have good experience with both. Keep in mind that it is a moving target both companies are adding features. Some architectural things that will hardly change: TFS has only Window Authentication, no application users (SSH keys will arrive one day); hooks architecture is quite different; Bitbucket has most data on the filesystem, while TFS has everything in the DB.