# git in TFS 2015

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2015

My organization is considering moving to git from TFVC for its .NET projects, and some of the devs remember reading that there were limitations to TFS's implementation of/integration with git.

A quick search of stackoverflow shows a number of questions from 2010-2013, which is *ages* ago in technology time, so I thought I'd ask again so we could take into account recent changes.

What are the reasons why a .NET shop--that wants to switch to git--should/shouldn't use TFS to host their git repository?

Comment: Tfs is turning very good as a git server. But it's up to you to look at what you want to do with it! But as git is decentralised, even a dumb git storage is enough for have all the advantages of git. Other things are extra. But in any case it can't be worse than TFVC... So, go! And with git it's easy to migrate, so no problem if you're not happy...

Comment: Edited it a bit to align with the point of the initial downvotes

Comment: And also git is the future of Tfs. Microsoft teams do not invest anymore in TFVC  and nearly all there team are moving to git. So the way to go. Jump in the wagon ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I found this article which has exactly the information I was looking for: 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2015/04/21/tfvc-git-support/

This question was very similar to what I was searching for, as well: [Team Foundation Server 2015 vs. Bitbucket Server (Stash)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33260419/team-foundation-server-2015-vs-bitbucket-server-stash)